# c# rabbitmq: passing bulk request to rabbit mq sever OR passing each object one by one

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I am new to rabbitmq. I am creating product based website which will have over 100k products. The prices of these products keep on changing frequently.

Every night we get bulk price update request for almost each product (around 100 000 of them). I have a choice to make with following type of collection:

```
class ProductPrice
{
  int productId;
  string productPrice;
}
```

1. Push each price update one by one to rabbitmq. [Each record in them dequeued in consumer and price is updated]
2. Push entire price update collection to rabbitmq directly. (almost 100 000) [Collection is dequeued, then iterated, then price is updated for each]
3. Push in bulk but in groups. (ex. group of 10 000) [Collection is dequeued, then iterated, then price is updated for each]

Which would be best approach considering all aspects?

Comment: This is very opinion based, probably to push in bulk with groups.  Down side of 1 by 1 is that you get the latency of the communication with SQL each update, (assuming this is going over the wire).  Pushing all at once could be an issue if there was an error or if you wanted to pause and continue your process later.  Pushing in bulk would have both benefit with out too much down side

Comment: What is lakh by the way?

Comment: @Evk: It is 1,00,000. Editted in the problem as well.

Comment: Rabbitmq is not designed for very large messages, and pushing 1 by 1 is not a good idea either, so I'd say push in batches.

Comment: any specific functionality rabbitmq provides for this? Or we should receive bulk update request and then push to rabbit mq server in chunks by doing c# collection operations.

Comment: Is there a real requirement to use rabbitmq for this? You say "Every night we get bulk price update", wouldn't it be simpler to create a sql script to directly update and avoid another process inbetween? Or do you get the updates one at a time?

Comment: We get price update through some third party. We have exposed api to receive collection of "ProductPrice" which we further process in queue.